# How do I limit a selection with a where without removing all of the entries that meet the condition in the join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

We calculate bonuses based on estimated work completed divided by hours paid. There is a person in our system who isn't paid by us and I want to remove him from the report.

In this query I am getting all of the tracked time on each batch for that user divided by the total time tracked on that batch, minus [name].

Batches have tasks which contain the estimated_nonrecurring and the estimated_recurring.
Batches have batch_logs which have the time_elapsed which is the time that the batch has been actually worked on.

What is happening is instead of selecting all the batches and then getting all the time that was tracked for that user in comparison to the total time tracked that wasn't tracked by [name], it is ignoring every batch that has [name] as an entry in it.

Here is my select statement for ratios.

```
SELECT user_time_by_batch.batch_id, userid, user_time_by_batch / total_time_by_batch as ratio FROM 
( 
SELECT SUM(time_elapsed) user_time_by_batch, userid, batch_id 
FROM batch_log 
inner join batches on batch_log.batch_id = batches.id 
Where start_time between (?) and (?) 
   and end_time is not null and time_elapsed BETWEEN \"00:00:00\" AND \"10:00:00\" 
   and batch_id not in (\"-1\", \"-2\", \"-3\", \"-4\", \"-5\", \"-6\", \"-7\", \"-8\", \"-9\", \"-10\", \"-11\", \"-12\", \"-13\", \"-14\", \"-15\", \"-16\", \"-17\") 
   and batches.operation_id = ? 
   and batch_log.userid = ? 
GROUP BY batch_id, userid 
)  user_time_by_batch 
INNER JOIN 
( 
SELECT SUM(time_elapsed) total_time_by_batch, batch_id 
FROM batch_log 
inner join batches on batch_log.batch_id = batches.id 
Where start_time between (?) and (?)  
  and end_time is not null and time_elapsed BETWEEN \"00:00:00\" AND \"10:00:00\" 
  and batch_id not in (\"-1\", \"-2\", \"-3\", \"-4\", \"-5\", \"-6\", \"-7\", \"-8\", \"-9\", \"-10\", \"-11\", \"-12\", \"-13\", \"-14\", \"-15\", \"-16\", \"-17\") 
  and batches.operation_id = ? 
  and batch_log.userid != 'name' 
GROUP BY batch_id 
) total_time_by_batch 
ON user_time_by_batch.batch_id = total_time_by_batch.batch_id ;
```

Comment: You say "it is ignoring every batch that has smacpherson as an entry in it."  I think that is exactly what you are telling it to do.  My guess is that you need to sum the time by user and batch (not batch alone) excluding McPherson in those sums and then sum those sums by batch to get your batch totals.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just trying to take him out of the batch: If bob works 6 hours and mac works 3 then bob should have 1.0 as a ratio instead of 6.66666

Comment: I don't know for sure but what i think you are doing now is saying "sum this up but don't select any batches with mac".  I think what you want to do is sum all the users who aren't mac and then sum their time to create your batch totals for comparison.  Then bob is a 1.0.  But I could be way off base.

Comment: I want to be able to get all the total for each person compared to all the persons in the batch as if mac didn't exist. So, basically, ignore every batch_log that mac is in, but not every batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I would consider trying is moving the batch_log.userid != 'smacpherson' in to the JOIN statement instead of in the WHERE clause. I'm not sure how best-practicey this is, but I've had success eliminating weird data issues by juggling that way.

So:

```
INNER JOIN 
( 
SELECT SUM(time_elapsed) total_time_by_batch, batch_id 
FROM batch_log 
inner join batches on batch_log.batch_id = batches.id and batch_log.userid != 'smacpherson'
Where start_time between (?) and (?)  
  and end_time is not null and time_elapsed BETWEEN \"00:00:00\" AND \"10:00:00\" 
  and batch_id not in (\"-1\", \"-2\", \"-3\", \"-4\", \"-5\", \"-6\", \"-7\", \"-8\", \"-9\", \"-10\", \"-11\", \"-12\", \"-13\", \"-14\", \"-15\", \"-16\", \"-17\") 
  and batches.operation_id = ?  
GROUP BY batch_id 
) total_time_by_batch
```

Comment: Will try this. Looks like it may be what I need.

Comment: I wanted to suggest that, but I didn't know if it would work. I don't have mySQL and Access threw up on a test join I did like that. Interested to see if you have sucess.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't understand joining on a select.

Comment: Did that end up working out for you, or are you still having problems?